# What is the most efficient way to take a list of Windows Event IDs and determine which audit policy enables logging of the event?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log

I have about 1500 Windows servers in my environment, 1000 or so 2012 R2 and 500 2016.

I have a list of about 150 event IDs that I have been told to log and archive. I don't know which audit policy I need to enable to successfully audit each. I don't want to turn on everything as the performance impact of doing that is too much. Is there a better way of approaching this task other than researching every event ID in my spreadsheet and determining which audit policy I need to enable?

Comment: Are you using Windows Event Forwarding and/or collecting the events into a SIEM? This will greatly assist with verifying your auditing is working as expected.

Comment: Yes, another team will collect the events via Splunk forwarder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew I bookmarked this site for a reason!

[Advanced Audit Policy – which GPO corresponds with which Event ID](https://girl-germs.com/?p=363)

Hope this answers your question.

Here's a couple more resources:

[Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 Security Auditing and Monitoring Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52630)

[Windows security audit events spreadsheet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50034)

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at https://system32.eventsentry.com, it has a complete list of all Windows security events with the associated audit subcategories.

I don't think there is a way to script it, but it's hopefully a starting point.